# Locus of points

Tags: geometry

> Given a sphere and a line outside it and taking a point $P$ on the
>   sphere and a point $Q$ on the line, what is the locus of the points of
>   the second intersection of $PQ$ with the sphere if we vary the
>   position of $Q$?

I tried solving this analyticaly but with no result ... any help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that as $Q$ varies on the line $PQ$ varies along the plane containing the line and $Q$. So all points on the sphere that lie on this plane work, except for $P$ itself (as this corresponds to when $Q$ is at infinity).

Comment: Congrats on 4K and +1 !